# how to create a netsuite email template with HTML and use freemaker in it to access the user data

Tags: javascript, html, freemarker, netsuite

hello i am trying to create a email template in netsuite with HTML and in that i want to show **Hi customer **name****. To achieve this i think we have to use the freemarker . can anyone help me how to write freemarker code in html.

```
<p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin-top:0;">Dear <h1>${contact.firstName}</h1>,</p>
```

In this code i want to print the customer first name instead of the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

that will do it. 
you have a number of options for generating the html.

If you use nlobjEmailMerger via nlapiCreateEmailMerger you would generate a standard email template; populate it with freemarker and static markup and then merge and send it.

for your use you'd do something like:

```
var merger = nlapiCreateEmailMerger(templateId); // templateId from a script parameter
merger.setEntity('contact', contactId);
var result = merger.merge();
nlapiSendEmail(fromId, contactId, result.getSubject(), result.getBody());
```

Be aware that when you create your template Netsuite validates the code so that you can only use standard records. I've had issues with custom records or when I want to add search results

The other way you can use free marker to generate an email is with a nlobjTemplateRenderer.

This allows you to supply an arbitrary text as a template and include records and search results under unique keys.

e.g.

```
var renderer = nlapiCreateTemplateRenderer();
renderer.setTemplate("<p style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; margin-top:0;">Dear <h1>${contact.firstName}</h1>,</p>"); // from a file maybe
renderer.addRecord('contact', nlapiLoadRecord('contact', contactId));
nlapiSendEmail(fromId, contactId, "Email Subject", renderer.renderToString());
```